# H2o Python: Combining XGB Holdout Predictions

Tags: python, h2o, xgboost

When using:

```
"keep_cross_validation_predictions": True
"keep_cross_validation_fold_assignment": True
```

in H2O's XGBoost Estimator, I am not able to map these cross validated probabilities back to the original dataset.  There is one documentation example for [R](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/cross-validation.html#combining-holdout-predictions) but not for Python (combining holdout predictions).

Any leads on how to do this in Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cross-validated predictions are stored in two different places -- once as a list of length k (for k-folds) in `model.cross_validation_predictions()`, and another as an H2O Frame with the CV preds in the same order as the original training rows in `model.cross_validation_holdout_predictions()`.  The latter is usually what people want (we added this later, that's why there are two versions).

Yes, unfortunately the [R example](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/cross-validation.html) to get this frame in the "Cross-validation" section of the H2O User Guide does not have a Python version ([ticket](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-5756?filter=-2) to fix that).  In the [`keep_cross_validation_predictions`](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/keep_cross_validation_predictions.html) argument documentation, it only shows one of the two locations.

Here's an updated example using XGBoost and showing both types of CV predictions:

```
import h2o
from h2o.estimators.xgboost import H2OXGBoostEstimator
h2o.init()

# Import a sample binary outcome training set into H2O
train = h2o.import_file("http://s3.amazonaws.com/erin-data/higgs/higgs_train_10k.csv")

# Identify predictors and response
x = train.columns
y = "response"
x.remove(y)

# For binary classification, response should be a factor
train[y] = train[y].asfactor()

# try using the `keep_cross_validation_predictions` (boolean parameter):
# first initialize your estimator, set nfolds parameter
xgb = H2OXGBoostEstimator(keep_cross_validation_predictions = True, nfolds = 5, seed = 1)

# then train your model
xgb.train(x = x, y = y, training_frame = train)

# print the cross-validation predictions as a list
xgb.cross_validation_predictions()

# print the cross-validation predictions as an H2OFrame
xgb.cross_validation_holdout_predictions()
```

The CV pred frame of predictions looks like this:

```
Out[57]:
  predict         p0        p1
---------  ---------  --------
        1  0.396057   0.603943
        1  0.149905   0.850095
        1  0.0407018  0.959298
        1  0.140991   0.859009
        0  0.67361    0.32639
        0  0.865698   0.134302
        1  0.12927    0.87073
        1  0.0549603  0.94504
        1  0.162544   0.837456
        1  0.105603   0.894397

[10000 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: This helps a lot.. can not thank you enough.. Just to connect the dots, So `xgb.cross_validation_holdout_predictions()` gives prediction from each 5(nfold) different models for their particular holdout is it?

Comment: Yep, exactly.  The predictions on each row are from when that row was part of the holdout set in the CV loop.

Comment: Awesome.. I think `xgb.cross_validation_holdout_predictions()` doesn't work when we have multiple classes because it shows None type when we use this method..

Comment: @AbhijeetArora Make sure that you set `keep_cross_validation_predictions = True` or it will not store the CV predictions.

Answer (score 1):

For Python there is [an example of this on GBM](https://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-ueno/2/docs-website/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/keep_cross_validation_predictions.html), and it should be exactly the same for XGB. According to that page, you should be able to do something like this:

```
model = H2OXGBoostEstimator(keep_cross_validation_predictions = True)

model.train(x = predictors, y = response, training_frame = train)

cv_predictions = model.cross_validation_predictions()
```

Comment: This is almost correct, but not the right method -- this method will return a list of CV pred frames instead of the CV preds in a frame, like OP is asking for.